# Loop through record lines method - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have this method:

```
@api.onchange('qty', 'consumed_qty')
def _remaining_func(self):
    for qty in self.isbn:
        if self.qty or self.consumed_qty:
            self.remaining_qty = self.qty +(-self.consumed_qty)
```

But I need it to loop through records of my line (One2many field), right now, if I add just one record it works just fine, but if I add two or more, it throws the `Expected singleton` error.

So, how can I loop with this method?

I have added the `for qty in self.isbn` but with no success.

This is the class where this method is declared:

```
class bsi_production_order_lines(models.Model):
    _name = 'bsi.production.order.lines'

    production_order = fields.Many2one('bsi.production.order', string="Production Orders")
    isbn = fields.Many2one('product.product', string="ISBN", domain="[('is_isbn', '=', True)]")
    qty = fields.Float(string="Quantity")
    consumed_qty = fields.Float(string="Consumed quantity")
    remaining_qty = fields.Float(string="Remaining quantity", compute="_remaining_func")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try:

```
@api.onchange('qty', 'consumed_qty')
def _remaining_func(self):
    for s in self:
        for qty in s.isbn:
            if s.qty or s.consumed_qty:
                s.remaining_qty = s.qty +(-s.consumed_qty)
```

I hope this help you.